# Using typescript how to define a type that returns same object with a promise for each value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to use a type (or interface) like this:

```
type FoodTable = {
  foodId: string;
  foodName: string;
};
```

And a function that accepts the type as a generic argument:

```
function promisifyData<T>(data): SomePromiseyData<T> {
  // code here
}
```

so if I invoke the function using `FoodTable` as the generic:

```
promisifyData<FoodTable>(someParam);

// returns:
{
  foodId: Promise {}, // resolves to string
  foodName: 'some name'
}
```

Basically I want to know how to define the  `SomePromiseyData` type.

Here is a link to the typing I'm trying to achieve:
[typescriptlang.org/play](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20FoodTable%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foodId%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20PromiseyData%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3F%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20%7C%20Promise%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20makePromiseyData%3CT%3E(data)%3A%20PromiseyData%3CT%3E%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20promiseyData%3A%20PromiseyData%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20key%20in%20data)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20promiseyData%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20Promise.resolve(data%5Bkey%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20promiseyData%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Type%20checking%20is%20not%20working%20as%20expected%20i.e.%20no%20failures!%0D%0AmakePromiseyData%3CFoodTable%3E(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foodId%3A%20'1'%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20okay%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20123%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%22name%22%20should%20be%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20invalidKey%3A%20'foo'%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%22invalidKey%22%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20FoodTable%0D%0A%7D)%3B)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `data` parameter has no type. It should be of type `T`:

```
function makePromiseyData<T>(data: T) { /*...*/ }
```

See [fixed version](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20FoodTable%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foodId%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20PromiseyData%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3F%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20%7C%20Promise%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20makePromiseyData%3CT%3E(data%3A%20T)%3A%20PromiseyData%3CT%3E%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20promiseyData%3A%20PromiseyData%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20key%20in%20data)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20promiseyData%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20Promise.resolve(data%5Bkey%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20promiseyData%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Type%20checking%20is%20not%20working%20as%20expected%20i.e.%20no%20failures!%0D%0AmakePromiseyData%3CFoodTable%3E(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foodId%3A%20'1'%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20okay%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20123%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%22name%22%20should%20be%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20invalidKey%3A%20'foo'%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%22invalidKey%22%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20FoodTable%0D%0A%7D)%3B).

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your `data` parameter as having a type: `data: T`.